# How do I fix mesh overlap?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I installed FCOM and QTP3 (in that order, with renaming files). However, some old meshes seem to overlap with the new ones:

[image: bug example]

Extra points on how to move the three food/thirst/sleep bars.

Comment: That's a LOD mesh problem, not something from QTP3 or FCOM. Something unrelated had gone wrong. Have you installed a LOD replacer lately?

Comment: The hunger/sleep/thirst bars are due to using a version of the needs mod that is expecting you to be using a UI replacer. Either uninstall your needs mod or use a version that is compatible with the UI you're using. Possibly, the needs mod's readme with have instructions or a utility for customising the UI placement, so start there.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Better Cities Permanent Resources-16513-5-3-0
Better Cities Resources v5-3-3-16513-5-3-3
Better Cities v5-3-3-16513-5-3-3
FCOM Superpack
LoadingScreens
QarlTP3
Unofficial Oblivion Patch - Manual Installer-5296-3-4-4. And a fresh Data/ directory. Might LOD leftovers lurk somewhere else?

Comment: @Tess Better Cities probably contains LOD meshes or interacts with the vanilla ones somehow. Check their instructions for anything related to LOD, since often there are extra steps than just extracting everything. They might have severals sets to choose one from, or require a utility to be run to update the LOD files to match the city changes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie cleaned up Better Cities, didn't help. Mods: http://sprunge.us/BNQI - I removed all of them except the basics, still didn't help.